# locally convex real space and denseness of

Tags: functional-analysis

This question was left as an exercise in my class of functional analysis and I am having a hard time proving this result.

> Question: Let E be a locally convex real space and $\phi: E\to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear form.
> Show that if $\phi$ is not continuous then $ker(\phi) $ is dense in H.

Attempt: I am not able to make much progress on this question and I think I need some hints.

I have been following functional analysis by Rudin for this course.

Comment: As far as I remember, it is a **theorem** in Rudin's book that a non-zerolinear functional is continuous if and only its kernel is not closed.

Comment: This is one of the contrapositives of theorem 1.18 (c)=> (a) chapter 1 of Rudins analysis you are using

Comment: @JulianCederlöfAlamosGuerra Thank you very much!